# the name of runtime created column

Tags: sql

The problem is when i try to use `where attendTimes >0` as constraint sql doesn't allow me to use the name of the column (`*Invalid column name 'attendTimes'.*`)

i tried to  us `where 'attendTimes' >0` and `where "attendTimes" >0` and `where attendTimes >0` but it didn't work

```
select served_name,
cast((select COUNT(*) FROM attend where served.served_id=attend.served_id and attendence_date>='2022-05-01')as int) AS attendTimes 

from served where **attendTimes** >0  order by 'attendTimes' desc;
```

Comment: When reminded that the `SELECT` happens more towards the tail end of the statement execution (and the `WHERE` clause happens earlier), it wouldn't be possible for SQL to filter the rows based on a column alias that it does not know about yet. 

A workaround would be to output the data in the right format within a `CTE` and filter the rows accordingly as you are trying to do here or to restructure the query and make use of `HAVING BY` depending on your comfort level.

Comment: I would make your query on the select statement a subquery on the from section making use of `having count` and left joining with the other table `served`